# Options for jQuery's on and dynamically added html

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's on method to bind button click events to an event.  I'm using the css class for assignment.

```
$('.removeBtn').on('click', function () {
    //CODE TO EXECUTE ON CLICK HERE
});
```

When my page loads, all my buttons with the class "removeBtn" are bound accordingly and work without a problem.

I also dynamically add buttons after the page has loaded.  These have the class "removeBtn", but do not fire.

I would like to add these new button's click event handler to my existing predefined handler, but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

All the examples I have found want to add the function event handler at creation.  This seems fine for a simple alert or call, but I have an ajax call and some string parsing and validation.  I don't want to repeat this code again.

I tried adding a function that I could call from both places, but this required some duplication too.

I'd like a way to simply create my new button and tell it to user the function defined in the code shown above.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click','.removeBtn', function () {
    //CODE TO EXECUTE ON CLICK HERE
});
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Can I do this at a lower level. Say, instead of document, on a div or parent like a table?

Comment: But only if you are not going to remove that element from DOM

Comment: I won't be removing the parent or container. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the listener the the document:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeBtn' function () {
    //CODE TO EXECUTE ON CLICK HERE
});
```